# Unable to Delete Computer account by DSRM cmd

Tags: active-directory

I am able to disable but cant delete computer account by using

```
dsquery computer -name %%i | dsmod computer -disabled | dsrm**
```

complete command is below

```
@echo off 
CLS
ECHO Now Deleting computer acocunt form AD...
TIMEOUT 1 > nul
Pause
FOR /f %%i in (C:\Commback\Script\Delete_CN.txt) do ( 
  dsquery computer -name %%i | dsmod computer -disabled | dsrm
)
```

Comment: are you shure this should be taged with php?

Comment: Can you post the error that your are getting for deleting the account ?

Comment: dsmod failed:No value specified for 'disabled'.
type dsmod /? for help.Description: This command deletes objects from the directory.

Comment: @BilalAbdul You are missing `yes` after `-disabled`. I think it should be `dsquery computer -name %%i | dsmod computer -disabled yes | dsrm`